# stutter with transform: scale while having scaling child element

Tags: html, css, transform, scale

Oi,

https://jsfiddle.net/jbwq6y87/7/

```
#box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box:hover{
 transform: scale(0.9);
}

#pic{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url (http://via.placeholder.com/500x500);
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#pic:hover{
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

I figured out everything for my wanted effect, but I noticed that the parent div has a light 1px stutter going on when it's ending its `transform: scale(0.9);`.

I know that the scaling of the child has something to do with it, but I don't exactly know what's causing the stutter. I'd appreciate some help to fix this very minor problem.

Answer (score 1):

Having a quicker transition duration for the child container than the parent container should solve this issue. This could be something like the following:

```
#box {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      transition: 0.5s ;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #box:hover{
     transform: scale(0.9);
    }

    #pic{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/500x500);
      background-size: cover;
      transition: 0.2s;
    }

    #pic:hover{
       transform: scale(1.2);
    }
```